# Cannot update NFS, the update manager shows packages but won't let me select them

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, nfs

I cannot update NFS. Ever since I upgraded from 10.04 LTS the update manager shows two NFS packages but it won't let me click them.

[image: Update Manager NFS Problem]

What should I do?

I tried:

```
sudo apt-get -oDebug::PkgProblemResolver=1 dist-upgrade
```

But It didn't help, eg:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Starting
Starting 2
Investigating (0) rpcbind [ amd64 ] < none -> 0.2.0-7ubuntu1 > ( net )
Broken rpcbind:amd64 Conflicts on portmap [ amd64 ] < 6.0.0-1ubuntu2.2 > ( net )
  Considering portmap:amd64 1 as a solution to rpcbind:amd64 1
  Holding Back rpcbind:amd64 rather than change portmap:amd64
Investigating (0) nfs-common [ amd64 ] < 1:1.2.0-4ubuntu4.2 -> 1:1.2.5-3ubuntu3 > ( net )
Broken nfs-common:amd64 Depends on rpcbind [ amd64 ] < none -> 0.2.0-7ubuntu1 > ( net ) (>= 0.2.0-6ubuntu1)
  Considering rpcbind:amd64 1 as a solution to nfs-common:amd64 1
  Holding Back nfs-common:amd64 rather than change rpcbind:amd64
Investigating (0) nfs-kernel-server [ amd64 ] < 1:1.2.0-4ubuntu4.2 -> 1:1.2.5-3ubuntu3 > ( net )
Broken nfs-kernel-server:amd64 Depends on nfs-common [ amd64 ] < 1:1.2.0-4ubuntu4.2 -> 1:1.2.5-3ubuntu3 > ( net ) (= 1:1.2.5-3ubuntu3)
  Considering nfs-common:amd64 1 as a solution to nfs-kernel-server:amd64 0
  Holding Back nfs-kernel-server:amd64 rather than change nfs-common:amd64
 Try to Re-Instate (1) nfs-common:amd64
 Try to Re-Instate (1) nfs-kernel-server:amd64
Done
Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  nfs-common nfs-kernel-server
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

I found a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nfs-utils/+bug/863741) similar to my problem, but I don't understand how I can "bump the priority of rpcbind in the archive to 'standard?" What does this mean? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nfs-utils/+bug/863741

It was fixed on  2012-06-07